# What is the difference in Work area, global structure, internal table?

Tags: abap

I am new to `ABAP` if anyone can tell me a website which I can refer to learn `ABAP` in depth or to understand it better, I have confusions with this `global structures`, `internal tables`, and `work areas`, someone please explain the need of them clearly with difference in each.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internal tables are a bit like lists in other languages, for instance like a List< T > in c#. They exist only in memory and only within the program they were defined in. I never encountered the term "global structure" as such, but structures are pretty much the same as in other languages. In abap they can be used to define the row structure of tables. Translate this to c# and you would end up with a class X with some properties (your row structure) and a List< X >, your internal table.

Work areas are essentially a single row of a defined structure. Work areas are for instance used to hold the contents of a single row when looping over an internal table. For instance:

```
data:
  it_vbak type standard table of vbak,
  wa_vbak type vbak.

select * from vbak into corresponding fields of table it_vbak.

loop at it_vbak into wa_vbak.

....

endloop.
```

this defines both an internal table it_vbak and a work area wa_vbak. Both are defined using the structure of the DDIC table VBAK, that is one of the SAP ERP tables and contains sales order header data. The example selects some data (in this case: all of it, not a good idea) into the internal table and then loops over the entries in the internal table. At the beginning of each loop, the contents of the current row are transferred to the work area. You can for instance manipulate the contents within the loop and then move the modifications back into the table by using the abap command modify:

```
modify it_vbak from wa_vbak.
```

You can define structures both within a program (using the TYPES keyword) and in the SAP ERP Data Dictionary (DDIC). The DDIC is globally available to all programs and contains definitions for tables, structures, views, table definitions, data elements and domains (and a bunch of stuff more which isn't too relevant here).

as a general reference for abap have a look at the [SAP Help portal](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/en/d3/2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm)